# Are infinite score allowed by default for "lowest score win"?

Tags: discussion, defaults, code-challenge

> 1. Are submissions acceptable if their worst case score is unbounded?

I think it worth a default exist

Answer (score 2):

## No, unless explicitly allowed.

- (Intuitively) it's quite unnatural to think about infinite score.
- It's uncommon to have infinite score, anyway. (for example, [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers don't have infinite score)
- There may be different "types" of infinities.

However, challenge posters may say that

> If an answer has the property XYZ, its score is considered to be infinite. All infinite-scored submissions are equal.

(there may be some tie-breakers, depends on the challenge)

or

> If an answer has the property XYZ, then instead consider the asymptotic complexity of the score when [...]. Solutions with lower asymptotic complexity are better.

etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Submissions need to be competitive.

That's all there is to it.  If you are aiming for a low score, and you end up with an infinite score, that's *probably* not competitive.

From the wiki:

> Be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. For example, an entry to a code golf contest needs to be golfed, and an entry to a speed contest should make some attempt to be fast.

In other words, if there is an infinite score (or an infinite-score tiebreaker), this should be decided case-by-case, on the basis of whether they are competitive or not.

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with whether it's *allowed*.

Comment: 2. "competitive" is relative. If you get ∞ score but all existing answers are, and you still beat them in a tie-breaker then your solution is still competitive.

Comment: I agree with the header, but I think the body should be more clear that infinite scores *can* in some theoretical situations be competitive, as @user202729 is saying.

Comment: So, is it allowed?

Comment: I'm saying here that we don't need a ruling one way or another.  We determine if submissions are *competitive* using subjective judgement, not a list of rules.  I don't think we need a rule saying "No infinite scores", as it is covered by "Be competitive".

Comment: @user202729 re #2. Competitive is not relative, but it is subjective.  Competitive means that there is clear effort towards achieving a low score.  It doesn't matter whether or not it is better than other answers.

Comment: @nathan If you already made a lot of effort and the score is still infinite, but it is better than all other answers, is it competitive?

Comment: The key here is "effort".  If that effort is visible, then yes.  This is how we judge competitive answers.  Whether it is better than all other answers is irrelevant.

Comment: So, it is allowed right? ... please make it explicit in the answer. (the reason why OP ask this question is probably ∞ is not considered to be a real number)

Comment: My answer is trying to shift the question, because I don't think the question "Can this submission have an infinite score" is the right question.  The correct question is "Is this submission competitive".

Answer (score 0):

## No for the 1st winning criticia but yes as a tie breaker

If the winner of other aspect has inf score on the tie breaker, that's fine; if more than one has same to here, treat the two inf as same unless explictly modified